# Access denied error with MySQL Connector/NET 6.9.9

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to port a Golang/MySQL app to C#/MySQL app using MySQL Connector/NET 6.9.9 that I installed via NuGet. My test app for verifying MySQL connectivity is very simple:

```
        string connStr = "server=192.168.5.3; protocol=tcp; pooling=false; uid=pdanuser; database=pdan; port=3306; pwd=<redacted>;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT <redacted> FROM <redacted> limit 100";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr[0] + " -- " + rdr[1]);
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

I get the following error:

```
Connecting to MySQL... 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Authentication to host '192.168.5.3' for user 'pdanuser' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'pdanuser'@'ip-192-168-5-35.internal' (using password: YES) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user 'pdanuser'@'ip-192-168-5-35.internal' (using password: YES) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(String authMethod, Boolean reset) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) 
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() 
at MySqlTester1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Dev\DotNet\MySqlTester1\MySqlTester1\Program.cs:line 15 
Done.
```

I know that I have no network or authentication problems because the Golang app successfully runs on this machine against the same MySQL database using the same username and password. I've googled for this error and seen some suggestions about uninstalling and reinstalling MySQL Connnector, but none of those have worked for me. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: I would still double-check if the user@host reported in the error messages has an entry in the user table, like `select host from mysql.user where user='pdanuser';`

Comment: @Guriandoro, there is an entry for that user in `mysql.user` and the value for `host` is `%`.

Comment: Strange... Can you try with another user/password? Does the password have any characters that may be being escaped differently? You can also try with a passwordless account. The error message is clearly about user permissions.

Comment: @Guriandoro, I tried with a new user that had no password and it worked. I tried again after adding a password consisting of only letters and numbers and it still worked. I changed the password on the 'pdanuser' account it worked, too. That's strange to me since its original password consisted only of letters. I don't know why it behaves that way, but I'm not blocked any more. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear, @Dan!